# second scenario in my cucumber feature file is not executing

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to learn Cucumber with selenium java . have written two scenario's , when i run my feature file which contains two scenarios , only scenario #1 is executing , for scenario #2 its throwing `Java null pointer exception`

```
Feature: POC of my framework works

Scenario: Login test
Given  I navigate to the Bugzilla website
When  I click on login
And I enter the values
Then  I check to see if i was successfully loged in or not

Scenario: File a bug test
Given  I navigate to the File a bug page
When  I click on widgets
And I enter the bug details
Then  Bug should be submited succefully
```

My step definition file :

```
package cucumber.features;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

public class StepDefinitions1 {

       protected WebDriver driver;
       protected String baseUrl;


       // Scenario 1
    @Given("^I navigate to the Bugzilla website$")
    public void I_navigate_to_the_Bugzilla_website() throws Throwable {

           driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            baseUrl ="https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-4.4-branch/index.cgi";
             driver.get(baseUrl);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @When("^I click on login$")
    public void I_click_on_login() throws Throwable {

        driver.findElement(By.id("login_link_top")).click();

    }

    @And("^I enter the values$")
    public void I_enter_the_values() throws Throwable {
        driver.findElement(By.id("Bugzilla_login_top")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Bugzilla_login_top")).sendKeys("jeevan.anekal@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Bugzilla_password_top")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Bugzilla_password_top")).sendKeys("testuser@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("log_in_top")).click();

    }

    @Then("^I check to see if i was successfully loged in or not$")
    public void I_check_to_see_if_i_was_successfully_loged_in_or_not() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Login Successfull");

    }


    // Scenario 2
    @Given("^I navigate to the File a bug page$")
    public  void I_navigate_to_the_File_a_bug_page() throws Throwable {

         driver.findElement(By.id("enter_bug")).click();

    }

    @When("^I click on widgets$")
    public void I_click_on_widgets() throws Throwable {

         driver.findElement(By.linkText("Widgets")).click();

    }

    @And("^I enter the bug details$")
    public void I_enter_the_bug_details() throws Throwable {
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("bug_severity"))).selectByVisibleText("trivial");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cf_drop_down"))).selectByVisibleText("---");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("rep_platform"))).selectByVisibleText("Macintosh");
        new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("op_sys"))).selectByVisibleText("Mac OS X 10.0");
        driver.findElement(By.id("short_desc")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("short_desc")).sendKeys("OS crashed");
        driver.findElement(By.id("comment")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("comment")).sendKeys("Os debugging issue");

    }

    @Then("^Bug should be submited succefully$")
    public void Bug_should_be_submited_succefully() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Bug submitted successfully");

    }

}
```

Comment: If there is an exception then please include the stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not calling the browser and navigating to the page in scenario 2

You need do do something similar to this

```
@Given("^I navigate to the File a bug page$")
    public  void I_navigate_to_the_File_a_bug_page() throws Throwable {
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();


            baseUrl ="https://landfill.bugzilla.org/bugzilla-4.4-nch/index.cgi";
             driver.get(baseUrl);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

         driver.findElement(By.id("enter_bug")).click();
    enter code here
    }
```

or use @Before hooks to initialize the browser

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind get your problem here. I had encountered similar problem before.

So when running the feature file, either by clicking on the run button from the bar or right click in the feature file then run..., take a look at what it says when actually clicking it. Because if you hover over a certain scenario and click run, it will only run that scenario, not the whole feature file where there is more than 1 scenarios.